# WhatWG - HTML5 tokenizer - official test cases?

Tags: html

## Short Version

Are there test vectors/test cases for a conforming [HTML Tokenizer?](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tokenization)

An example would be a sample of HTML:

```
<!doctype html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head></head>\r\n<body></body>\r\n</html>
```

And you are given the expected tokens:

- <kbd>doctype("html")</kbd>
- <kbd>character(`LF`)</kbd>
- <kbd>startTag("html")</kbd>
- <kbd>character(`LF`)</kbd>
- <kbd>startTag("head")</kbd>
- <kbd>endTag("head")</kbd>
- <kbd>character(`LF`)</kbd>
- <kbd>startTag("body")</kbd>
- <kbd>endTag("body")</kbd>
- <kbd>character(`LF`)</kbd>
- <kbd>endTag("html")</kbd>

## Long Version

There is a web-site ([WebPlatformTests.org](https://web-platform-tests.org/)) dedicated to creating tests so that *HTML Tokenizer* implementations can test their conformance:

> The web-platform-tests project is a cross-browser test suite for the [Web-platform stack](https://platform.html5.org/). Writing tests in a way that allows them to be run in all browsers gives browser projects confidence that they are shipping software which is compatible with other implementations, and that later implementations will be compatible with their implementations.

### HTML5 Tokenizer test class

In their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/tree/master/html), they have a Python-based [HTML Tokenizer test unit:](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/7b0ebaccc62b566a1965396e5be7bb2bc06f841f/tools/third_party/html5lib/html5lib/tests/tokenizer.py)

```
class TokenizerTestParser(object):
    def __init__(self, initialState, lastStartTag=None):
        self.tokenizer = HTMLTokenizer
        self._state = initialState
        self._lastStartTag = lastStartTag

    def parse(self, stream, encoding=None, innerHTML=False):
        # pylint:disable=unused-argument
        tokenizer = self.tokenizer(stream, encoding)
        self.outputTokens = []
```

And i see how it tokenizes some HTML, and tests the returned list of tokens against some reference. But i can't find where it gets the test vectors from.

### HTML Parsing Test Folder

The [Web Platform Tests home](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/tree/master/html) also documents how to navigate the repository to find the tests you want:

> ## HTML
>
> This directory contains tests for HTML.
>
> Sub-directory names should be based on the URL of the corresponding part of the multipage-version specification. For example, the URL of "8.3 Base64 utility methods" is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#atob. So the directory in WPT is [webappapis/atob/](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/html/webappapis/atob).

In my case i am looking at the spec:

- [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/**parsing.html#parsing**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing)

Which should mean i **should** need a directory in WPT named **"parsing/parsing"**. Except there is no **parsing** folder:

[image]

### WhatWG specification

The HTML 5 specification has a link to **"Tests"**:

[image]

But that goes to what i already mentioned above - Web Platform Tests.

### Non-standard test cases

In the absence of any formal test vectors, i did find a guy who wrote an (intentionally) [non-conforming HTML tokenizer](https://github.com/tildeio/simple-html-tokenizer/blob/master/tests/tokenizer-tests.ts).

Some of the test cases are wrong (they simply violate the HTML5 spec). But at least he does have a nice collection of about 40 test cases. But about 1/3rd of them violate HTML5.

Given that the Web Platform Tests specifically has Tokenizer tests: it seems to me that it must have Tokenizer tests *somewhere*.

But where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Parser_tests

## Long answer

[This question](https://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2013-March/039304.html) on the whatwg mailing list from 2013:

> Hello everyone.
>
> I was wondering if there is some sort of tests for the Tokenizer along with the correct output of tokens as well as a way of representing tokens.
> What I have in mind is running the tokenizer on some HTML input and printing the tokens in the same way the correct output is written.
> I will  then be comparing the result I have with the correct one provided character by character. :)

Which led to [the answer](https://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2013-March/081578.html):

> http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/source/browse/#hg%2Ftestdata%2Ftokenizer
>
> http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Parser_tests has some documentation of the
> format.

The Google Code link is obviously dead, but the wiki page does explain it:

> ## Parser tests
>
> [html5lib-tests](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-tests) is a suite of unit tests for use by implementations of the HTML spec. The aim is to produce implementation-independent, self-describing tests that can be shared between any groups working on these technologies. The parser tests live in the `tokenizer` and `tree-construction` directories, both of which contain README files describing the test format.

Which links to the (current) GitHub page, and the **tokenizer** folder of test cases:

[image]

The test cases are a series of JSON files, each containing an array of test cases:

```
{
   "description":"Empty end tag with following comment",
   "input":"a</><!--b-->c",
   "output":[["Character", "a"], ["Comment", "b"], ["Character", "c"]],
}
```

Meaning:

- **Description**: Empty end tag with following comment
- **Input**: `a</><!--b-->c`
- **Tokens**: <kbd>Character("a")</kbd> <kbd>Comment("b")</kbd> <kbd>Character("c")</kbd>